# Log the EMR Step ID during runtime or pass it as an argument to the Job

Tags: scala, apache-spark, amazon-emr

I want to use the "Step ID" in the path of my output file so that I know the output of each run of the EMR (Spark) application. How do I access it in my Scala Spark application?

[image]

Comment: While this isn't the exact answer you're looking for, have you explored AWS step functions for submitting EMR tasks. You get a response payload with step ID and job status.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way of passing EMR step id to the step script.
If it is really required, you may want to try this:

1. Use an identifier in your spark application and pass it as an argument along with the cluster id.
2. In your driver, use the emr list steps [API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/emr/list-steps.html) and describe step API to figure out the corresponding step id.
3. Continue with your application by with the step id you found.

This is a bit indirect or hackish way but might work for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

One way to ascertain which step is currently running, from inside the step, is to reference the current working directory.  The last 15 or so characters of the current directory is the same as the step id being executed.

In AWS EMR, an export of the current/working directory allows the current step to be used inside the shell as an environment variable.  The trimming of the current/working directory to only include everything after 'S-' prefix makes for a unique-to-the-step identifier in places where dashes are not allowed.

Below is a shell script example, which could be adapted for use subsequently in Spark or elsewhere.

```
export pwd=`pwd`
echo -e "\n\n### Execution is occurring the following directory:  $pwd\n\n"

export STEP=${pwd#*-}
echo -e "\n\n### EMR STEP ID: $STEP (not including the S- prefix) \n\n"
```